# What are the package name for google meet in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, android-manifest, microsoft-teams, google-meet

I wanted to know the **package name for Google meet in Android and iOS**. Currently I know the package name for **Zoom and Teams in Android manifest**. This is my **Android manifest code** where I'm specifying the **package name for Zoom and Teams**

```
<queries>
        <package android:name="us.zoom.videomeetings" />
        <package android:name="com.microsoft.teams" />
</queries>
```

in **iOS** I need the **property for both Teams and google meet**. This is the **Info.plist code** where I'm specifying the **property for Zoom**

```
<string>10</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array/>
    <key>Custom Property</key>
    <string>zoomus</string>
```

I checked for the solution but **I didn't find the package name or property anywhere for google meet**. I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Google Meet" has the package name :

```
com.google.android.apps.meetings
```

"Microsoft Teams" has the package name :

```
com.microsoft.teams
```

"Google Chat" has the package name :

```
com.google.android.apps.dynamite
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check Android package with Google Play Store link, its an id:

```
link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.meetings

package: com.google.android.apps.meetings
```

Comment: So do you mean com.google.android.apps.meetings is the package name for google meet in Android and iOS?

Comment: Any clue on how can I find the ios package name for google meet? Because I can't find that in the documentation.